# What does "href" stand for in HTML?

Tags: html, tags, anchor, terminology

I understand what the "href" attribute in the anchor tag (`<a />`) is for, but what does the "h" stand for?

Comment: Interestingly, the HTML specification, whilst defining the href attribute's meaning, doesn't appear to say what it stands for. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-href

Answer (score 132, accepted):

HREF stands for "Hypertext Reference".

Source: https://www.w3.org/Provider/ServerWriter.html

Comment: That tutorial was written by Tim Berners-Lee himself. At least it has his name at the bottom. It probably doesn't get more authoritative than this.

Comment: interestingly enough, I most often use it in the <link> tag to link the css document which is not hypertext at all.

Comment: @Xitcod13 you might want to check its usage in an [anchor](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag.

Answer (score 16):

[Hypertext REFerence](http://www.library.cornell.edu/design/dsigngloss.html)

Comment: The link is dead!

Answer (score 6):

the h stands for hypertext- in mathematics, hyperspace means greater than 3 dimensions. Got to love the superlative!

Comment: I tried looking for it but didn't get any. Can you help me with some citation which talks about this definition of hyper in mathematics.

Comment: HI @RBT looks like I miss-spoke. in mathematics, rather than 'hyper' it's 'hyperspace' that means greater than 3 dimensions. Hyper as a prefix means "over, above, beyond, exceedingly, to excess," I have edited my answer, hope it helps! Further edit, it looks like the collins dictionary does define hyperspace in ancient mathematics as being greater than 4 dimensions: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hyperspace but I don't have a citation.

Answer (score 4):

The official name is supposedly (H)ypertext (REF)erence, but I always liked to think of it as Hyperlink Reference.