# What does the "a" in "<a href="url">link text</a>" stand for?

Tags: html

See question: I don't see why hyperlinks are called "a"?

Comment: John can you point me to the Google search that answers my question?

Comment: It stands for "anchor"

Comment: Sure: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=What+does+the+%E2%80%9Ca%E2%80%9D+in+%E2%80%9C%3Ca+href%3D%E2%80%9Durl%E2%80%9C%3Elink+text%3C%2Fa%3E%E2%80%9D+stand+for%3F

Comment: Thanks, my Google request is far easier now that I know what I am looking for :)

Comment: @Mike eh I guess I should have tried my question as a request. I realize my question seem stupid but I don't see the point in being harsh, the answer is literally 6 letters long.

Comment: I'm not trying to be harsh, it's just what the answer is. And yes, the answer was very simple to find and reply with. That's why people are annoyed you didn't just do it yourself.

Comment: @Mike that's what I tried to tell you : I  did search Google with a combination of hyperlink, href and a but as you might guess "a" is not very decisive in a search and I only found out pages explaining how to make an hyperlink... That's typically the kind of subject when humans are still superior to machines, hence my decision to ask you guys.

Comment: Funnily enough this question that seemed stupid to me was very positively received, go figure...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586169/what-does-href-stand-for-in-html?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a" stands for Anchor text

The anchor text, link label, link text, or link title is the visible, clickable text in a hyperlink. The words contained in the anchor text can determine the ranking that the page will receive by search engines. Since 1998, some web browsers have added the ability to show a tooltip for a hyperlink before it is selected. Not all links have anchor texts because it may be obvious where the link will lead due to the context in which it is used. Anchor texts normally remain below 60 characters. Different browsers will display anchor texts

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_text

Answer (score 1):

"a" stands for anchor.

You can look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Anchor for more informations